# DHCP server does not provide correct filename for PXE

Tags: dhcp, pxe-boot, dhcp-server, isc-dhcp

I'm trying to configure PXE server for both Legacy/UEFI support. So I need to provide different bootloaders based on architecture of machine.

Here's part of `dhcpd.conf`:

```
option architecture-type code 93 = unsigned integer 16 ;

next-server 10.10.10.10;
if option  architecture-type = 00:07 {
  filename "grubx64.efi";
} else {
  filename "pxelinux.0";
}
```

This block doesn't seem to work at all. Whatever machine I boot from, no matter BIOS or UEFI, the server provides `pxelinux.0`. And I am sure that machine provides the correct information about architecture(option 93) - I looked at the contents of the package using `tcpdump`.

I have already tried to wrap it in a class as shown in the Red Hat examples.
I'm trying to create new hosts, so `dhcpd.leases` with `supersede server.filename = "pxelinux.0";` is not the issue.

I'm using ISC DHCP server 4.2.5 on CentOS 7, files provided with TFTP

Answer (score 0):

My bad, that I didn't post whole `dhcpd.conf`

There is a line about using omapi and turned out, that another program was in charge of creating `dhcpd.leases` file with hardcoded bootloader name.